# How can I create a menu in PHP from files in a directory

Tags: php, file, menu, directory

I'm very new to PHP and would like some help creating a menu from files contained in a  directory. As I add files i'd like the menu to automatically add an item.

The files in the directory are .htm files and the naming convention is year, then month separated by an underscore i.e, 2013_6.htm (June 2013)

I would like to be able to read the files and then create a menu from those.

I have managed to create a sorted array of the files, like this (which works fine):

```
$dir = "$cal_path";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if ($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
    $files[] = $filename;
    }
}
sort($files);
```

How do I now get this array of files into a menu item list that I can then style with CSS, something like this, where xxxx is the year from the filename and yy is the month from the file name.

```
$cal_menu = 

<ul>
 <li><a href="$base_url/calendar_view?year=xxxx&month=yy">June 2013</a></li>
 <li>etc</li>
 <li>etc</li>
</ul>
```

I created an array of months and corresponding month names

```
$CalendarMonth = array("1"=>"January","2"=>"February","3"=>"March","4"=>"April","5"=>"May","6"=>"June","7"=>"July","8"=>"August","9"=>"September","10"=>"October","11"=>"November","12"=>"December");
```

I hope I have explained my problem properly.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: tip: check out the `scandir` function

Comment: `while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))` WHAT??

Comment: @phpNoOb nothing particularly confusing about that ... but he should just use `scandir` :P

Comment: What difference does it make, they're both fine ways to get a list of files in the directory. That's not really what his question is about.

Comment: that's why i commented instead of answered. that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

**EDIT:** as you want to save that output on a variable.

```
rsort($files);
$cal_menu = '<ul>';

foreach($files as $file){ 
    preg_match('/(\d{4})_(\d.*).htm/i', $file, $date);
    $mont_name = $CalendarMonth[$date[2]];

    $cal_menu .= '<li><a href="$base_url/calendar_view?year='.$date[1].'&month='.$date[2].'">'.$mont_name.' '.$date[1].'</a></li>';
}
$cal_menu .= '</ul>';
```

This code set the output of every *li* item in the format you required: *?year=xxxx&month=yy*

See it working [here](http://eval.in/30545).

Comment: thank you.  I tried this and got a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: I see, you want to save the output on _$cal_menu_. In that case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ Luigi Siri - thank you very much.  That is almost there. my files are 2013_6.htm 2013_11.HTM ETC ETC.  I notice the output for my file 2013_6.htm i get a url calendar_view,php?year=213&month=06 than than month=6.  How do I correct this?  Thank you again.

Comment: @Ruf1, totally my fault. I thought you wanted 2 digits there. Try now.

Comment: @ Luigi Siri - thankyou again.  It works perfectly.  My last problem it seems it to list these menu URL's in ascending order (closest date going upwards).  I have three test files in the directory 2013_11.htm, 2013_6.htm and 2014_4.htm.  The output currently shows them as November 2013, June 2013, April 2014.  Is it possible to sort them as ascending?

Comment: @ Luigi Siri.  Thanks.  If you look at my original post I had included sort($files) but for some reason they are being listed out of order.

Comment: that didnt work either.  That ordered it as 2014_4.htm,
2013_6,htm, 2013_11,htm, 2012_10,htm.

Comment: @ Luigi Siri - it seems that using sort() works, but only 2013_11.htm is out of place.  It seems to read it 1 rather than 11.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30093/discussion-between-luigi-siri-and-ruf1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
// pathinfo will return an array containing
// dirname,basename,extension,filename then use extract
// to convert the array into variables
extract(pathinfo($file)); 
echo "<li><a href="$file">$filename</a></li>"
}
</ul>
```

read more about pathinfo http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
read more about extract https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    preg_match('/^(\d{4})_(\d{1,2}}/', $file, $match); // Parse filename into YYYY_MM
    $year = $match[1];
    $month = $match[2];
    $monthname = $CalendarMonth[$month];
    // Interpolate these into HTML output
    echo "<ul>
          <li><a href='$base_url/calendar_view?year=$year&month=$month'>$monthname $year</a></li>
          <li>etc</li>
          </ul>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this one.  I tried it and got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS

Comment: I fixed the missing quote around the regexp

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop in which you extract data from each filename with `pathinfo`. You could do this inside your existing loop, but here it is as a `foreach`:

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach($files as $filename) {
     $f_info = pathinfo($dir . '/' . $filename);
     $extension_length = strlen('.' . $f_info['extension']);

     $f_parts = substr($f_info['filename'], 0, -$extension_length);
     $year = $f_parts[0];
     $month = $f_parts[1];

     echo '<li><a href="' . $base_url . '/calendar_view?year=' . $year .
          '&month=' . $month . 'yy">' . $CalendarMonth[$month] . ' ' .
          $year . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

You might want to use `array_key_exists` to verify that `$month` actually exists in `$CalendarMonth` before using `$CalendarMonth[$month]`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but all that was output was the number 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kd8-rz3) example. It should give you an idea.